# In Oracle APEX, how can I dynamically change the LOGOUT_URL in order to control which page they see when they sign out?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to APEX, and I have an APEX app that is being used by two different groups of users. I want to change the LOGOUT_URL for each type of user so they will arrive at their correct login page after they sign out. One group is being authenticated via this application's custom authentication scheme. The other group is authenticated via another APEX app and then they have access to the main app through session sharing.

I can set a Post-Logout URL for the app (either the Home Page or a custom URL), but I need to set this logout URL according to the type of user. I thought of applying an Application Computation, but the LOGOUT_URL is built in and is not one of my Application Items. Please let me know how I can dynamically set the LOGOUT_URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the logout url probably isn't possible but here is a workaround. Let's say the app through which one group of users comes in is app 100, the app that is shared is 200

In the navigation bar of app 200, create 2 "Sign Out" entries, with a condition so the first one only shows for users that are custom authenticated and the 2 one only showing for users coming from app 100

Set target `&LOGOUT_URL.` for the entry that is visibly by the custom authenticated users.

For the users coming from app 100, I'd do the following. In app 100, create a custom "logout" page and make app 100:logout the target for the "Sign Out" nav bar entry that is visible by those users.

The logout page in app 100 should only have a before header page process with source:

```
begin
  apex_authentication.logout(:APP_SESSION, :APP_ID);
end;
```

And that's it. Now each of the users see a "Sign out" link in the navbar, but depending on who they are it'll log out in a different way.